# cannot open database due to login failure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to add a local sql server database to my project for deployment purposes.  I added an existing sql server .mdf file as local database in visual studio.  I can query the database in visual studio and both see and add data to my tables. I copied and pasted the connection string from the properties menu to my code.  See the connection string below.  (The commented out string works with the external sql server database)

```
// return "Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS2;Initial Catalog=" + mCatalog + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Context Connection=False";
return "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=" + mCatalog + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
```

The error message I see is:  Cannot open database "myDatabase" requested by the login.  The login failed for user 'RYANPC\ryan'.

However, when I look at the properties of the database I attached, I can see 'RYANPC\ryan' Under security for Logins.

[image]

I tried adding the following to the connection string, but I still have no luck:  User ID=RYANPC\ryan;pwd=mypassword"

I am completely stuck.

Comment: Give it the proper rights to your database. Since it is your own local db. You can give it sysadmin under Properties on your user -> Server roles -> Select sysadmin - Goto user mapping under Properties and check your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A login is just one piece of the puzzle.

You should also create a Role and a User in the database.

Give the Role the necessary permissions. Make the User a member of the Role. Finally assign the login to the User.

Comment: I cannot see a way to open this database in sql server management studio.  So, I am working with the 'Sql Server Object Explorer' in visual studio.  I see a folder for 'Server Roles', but I am not allowed to add a new role or modify an existing role.

Comment: They are under the database > Security (so not Server objects but database objects). If you don't need custom permissions you can just add a user with  existing built in roles such as db_datareader / db_datawriter.

Comment: I think this is where I'm stuck.  I changed the image above to give a more accurate reflection of where I am trying to change the localdb settings.  When i right click on 'Server Roles' I get no options to add a new role, only to refresh the existing roles.

Comment: It's not a Server Role. It's a role on the database itself. You need to connect to the database in Server Explorer - open it up - and look in there for the setting (under the Security Folder). Server Roles is where you find permission that cover the entire server, such as permission to create and drop databases.